# ParseCloud error 102, cannot query through pointers

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have some problem with parse cloud js.

After I save ParseMessage object, I want to check 3 pointer (product, sender and recipient) in other class (MessageTracker). With the base 3 query there is no problem, but when I call `insideQuery.notEqualTo("sender", result.get("owner"));` I got an error:

> 102 : pointer field sender needs a pointer value

This "owner" also a pointer to user class, like the others (sender and recipient), but this time parse cloud send an error.

(On console I see, that the object ids are valid values, so I have the right objects)

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("ParseMessage", function(request) {
    var message = request.object;

    var product = message.get("product");
    var sender = message.get("sender");
    var recipient = message.get("recipient");

    var query = new Parse.Query("Product");

    query.get(product.id, {
      success: function(result) {

        console.error("prod owner: " + result.get("owner").id + " sender: " + sender.id + " reciever: " + recipient.id);

        var insideQuery = new Parse.Query("MessageTracker");

        insideQuery.equalTo("product", product);
        insideQuery.equalTo("sender", sender);
        insideQuery.equalTo("recipient", recipient);

        insideQuery.notEqualTo("sender", result.get("owner"));

        insideQuery.find({
            success: function(results) {

                console.error("count: " + results.length);

            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
            }
        }); 

      },
      error: function(object, error) {

      }
    }); 
});
```

Any good advice?

**UPDATE**
I maybe found the problem. Parse do not let us check `equalTo` and `notEqualTo` for the same pointer in the query. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try building out the pointer:

```
var ownerPointer = {
    __type: 'Pointer',
    className: <className>,
    objectId: result.get("owner").id
};
insideQuery.notEqualTo("sender", ownerPointer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately the same error